# How to speed up this mySQL query (filesort issue)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following MYSQL query:

```
select IF(`User`='101',`Friend`,`User`) as `Kto`,`Recent` 
from `friends` 
WHERE (`User`='101' || `Friend`='101') AND `Status`=1 
HAVING `Kto` IN (SELECT `Id` FROM `users` WHERE `Id`=`Kto` AND `Online`>='100') 
ORDER by Recent DESC limit 11
```

Using `ORDER by Recent DESC` query takes longer (Showing rows 0 - 10 (11 total, Query took 0.0090 sec) [Recent: 9337663 - 7683644])

If I do not use Order by, it is too mutch faster (Showing rows 0 - 10 (11 total, Query took 0.0005 sec))

In explain query with ORDER by shows filesort, which i guess is the slowness problem, see below:

[image]

Could you please help me, how to get rid of this filesort, or how to optimize this query, or help me to add proper index just for this query?

Comment: read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: thanks for link, but I do not what is obstacle in my query...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, mate:

```
SELECT
    IF(f.`User`='101',f.`Friend`,f.`User`) as `Kto`,
    f.`Recent`
FROM
    `friends` f
    INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.`Id` IN (f.`User`, f.`Friend`)
WHERE 
    (f.`User` = '101' || f.`Friend` = '101')
    AND f.`Status` = 1
    AND u.`Online` >= '100'
ORDER BY
    f.Recent DESC
LIMIT 11;
```

Comment: thank you for fast reposne, but this takes more longer (Showing rows 0 - 10 (11 total, Query took 0.0134 sec) [Recent: 9348273 - 8404480]) maybe i should create special index for this?

Comment: I think so, creating an index for this can help the speed of select queries.

Comment: can you please advice me how should this index looks like? I need to create index just for this specific query, thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not good at explaining but here's a link where I've learned it the most: http://use-the-index-luke.com/ Target columns for indexing can be: `friends`.`User`, `friends`.`Friend`, and `friends`.`Status`